# XOR using a 4:1 Mux in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, xor

I need to create XOR with 4:1 Mux (I know that it's easier without a Mux...)

I found this useful example for 4:1

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity multiplexer4_1 is
port (
      i0 : in std_logic;
      i1 : in std_logic;
      i2 : in std_logic;
      i3 : in std_logic;
     sel : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
     bitout : out std_logic
     );
end multiplexer4_1;

architecture Behavioral of multiplexer4_1 is
begin

process(i0,i1,i2,i3,sel)
begin
case sel is
  when "00" => bitout <= i0;
  when "01" => bitout <= i1;
  when "10" => bitout <= i2;
  when others => bitout <= i3; 
end case; 
end process;

end Behavioral;
```

But I'm somehow confused how to tell the mux to output 1 when 01 or 10 is the input and 0 otherwise.
Can I assign values to i0-i3? Sorry I'm new to VHDL

Comment: How many inputs does you XOR gate have to have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity xor4_1 is
port (
  --i0 : in std_logic;
  --i1 : in std_logic;
  --i2 : in std_logic;
  --i3 : in std_logic;
 sel : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
 bitout : out std_logic
 );
end xor4_1;

architecture Behavioral of xor4_1 is

signal    i0 : std_logic;
signal    i1 : std_logic;
signal    i2 : std_logic;
signal    i3 : std_logic;



begin

process(i0,i1,i2,i3,sel)
begin
case sel is
  when "00" => bitout <= i0;
  when "01" => bitout <= i1;
  when "10" => bitout <= i2;
  when others => bitout <= i3; 
end case; 
end process;

-- Now just hardcode the input bits to the appropriate values.
-- I might be mistaken, but I'm pretty sure this is how the implementation tool
--s actually would implement an XOR gates.
i0    <= '0';
i1    <= '1';
i2    <= '1';
i3    <= '0';

end Behavioral;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have to build an XOR gate with 2 inputs. One possibility would be to connect the two inputs to `sel(0)` and `sel(1)` respectively. You can then connect constant values to your remaining inputs `i0` to `i3` such that the truth table of your MUX4 is the same as for an XOR gate.

Comment: In other words, when you instantiate your mux, connect '0', '1', '1', '0' to i0, i1, i2, i3 respectively.

Comment: So how can I do this in VHDL? Do you have an example for me?

Comment: @EML: The question sounds like homework to me. I wanted give the OP a shot at solving the problem himself.

Comment: @AzzUrr1: What is giving you problems? You could instantiate a MUX4 entity and then connect appropriate signals to its inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 1):

Your MUX connects one input to the output based on the select signals.

If you imagine the select signals are the "inputs" to your XOR gate, you just need to figure out what the output should be for each combination of the XOR inputs (the select signals).  Then wire up the MUX inputs such that the right level comes out for each select input.

The VHDL syntax for that is just

```
inst: entity work.multiplexer4_1 
port map
(
   i0 => '1'; -- or '0'

etc..

   sel => xor_input_signals;
   bitout => xor_output_signal
);
```